# For what real values of $\alpha$ does $\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{x(x+1)}$ converge

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, analysis

Given a random variable $X$ with probability mass function

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{x(x+1)} \text{ if } x = 1,2,...
\\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

If we let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we consider
$\mathbb{E}\left[X^{\alpha} \right] $. I want to figure out for which values of $\alpha$ that that the expectation of the $\alpha$-power of $X$ is convergent.
For any $\alpha$ we have by the definition of expectation that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X^{\alpha} \right] = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^{\alpha} \cdot f\left(x \right) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{\alpha}}{x(x+1)}
$$
I also know that the expectation of random variable exists if the sum is absolutely convergent.

How do I go about testing absolute convergence for a series?

Comment: It comverges if and only if $\alpha<1$ by comparison with $\sum n^p$ which converges if and only if $p<-1$.

Comment: So $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{\alpha}}{x(x+1)} = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x+1} >\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x} = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-2}$ and then applying your suggestion?

Comment: I think you have some typos, but more or less.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm messing up the direction of the inequalities, but I think I get the gist of it. Thank you!